# Gtk3 `set_fixed_height_from_font` does not produce cells of correct height

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, lablgtk

I am trying to make a tree view in Gtk3 such that each row has the size of two rows of text. The following is a minimal working example:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *window;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 100, 100);

  /* init store */
  GtkListStore *store;
  store = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);

  /* add items */
  int COL = 0;
  GtkTreeIter iter1, iter2;
  gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter1);
  gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter1, COL, "hello", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter2);
  gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter2, COL, "world", -1);

  /* make tree view */
  GtkWidget *list;
  GtkWidget *vbox;
  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  list = gtk_tree_view_new();
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), list, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  /* make column */
  GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
  GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Items",
          renderer, "text", COL, NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), column);
  gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

  /********* This doesn't work as expected! *********/
  gtk_cell_renderer_text_set_fixed_height_from_font(GTK_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT(renderer),2);

  /* main */
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

I am using [`set_fixed_height_from_font`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.CellRendererText.set_fixed_height_from_font.html) to set the height based on the font. Now the above produces

[image]

which has entries of size one rather than two.

Is this a bug in Gtk, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you noticed a "blah" has been truncated in your second snapshot. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @BobMorane Please see my edit for simpler example

Comment: Ok, you example works, I was able to reproduce the problem. By the way, thx for translating to C.

Comment: @BobMorane do you think I should report this as a bug?

Comment: I have looked at it some but did not have enough time to conclude. What bugs me is the comment about the "y_pad" and the "font" properties in the documentation. I have tried changing the "y_pad" and the vertical space expanded, but I don't understand what's the deal really as of now... Might be a bug, but also might not. Maybe it's just, once again, underdocumented.

Comment: @BobMorane Thanks for checking it out, I found this cryptic too. From what I gather, [set_fixed_height_from_font](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/gtk/gtkcellrenderertext.c#L1862) sets a flag which is then checked in [get_size](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/gtk/gtkcellrenderertext.c#L1619), which seems to be the code that computes the height..

Comment: I at least found a workaround hack, will post later.

Comment: I tried again and failed... I would report this as a bug. From its name and documentation (and even the code link you posted), it seems it should work.

Comment: @BobMorane Thanks for your input, I wasn't sure. I'll report now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_fixed_height_form_font` works in Gtk2, but behaves differently in Gtk3.

My solution (in the OCaml interface, as originally posted), was to compute the height explicitly following [cell_renderer_text.get_size](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/gtk/gtkcellrenderertext.c#L1619):

```ml
let default_font = "11"

let calc_font_height ?(ypad = 0) (num_lines : int) : int =
  let fm = Cairo_pango.Font_map.get_default () in
  let ctx = Cairo_pango.Font_map.create_context fm in
  let fd = Pango.Font.from_string default_font in
  let metrics = Pango.Context.get_metrics ctx fd None in
  let ascent = Pango.Font.get_ascent metrics in
  let descent = Pango.Font.get_descent metrics in
  GPango.to_pixels((GPango.from_pixels ypad) + (num_lines * (ascent + descent)))
```

then we set the attributes

```ml
(GTree.cell_renderer_text [`FONT default_font; `YPAD 2;
                           `HEIGHT (Font.calc_font_height ~ypad:2 2)],
                          ["text",col])
```

Comment: I'm curious, did you end up filing a bug ?

Comment: @BobMorane Yes, unfortunately is was closed because "GTK2 and GTK3 are different API versions, and as such they don't necessarily behave the same. It's expected." I'm annoyed because the documentation should at least have been different, considering the behavior is different.

Comment: Sorry for posting in OCaml, I don't want to spend any more time on this, hence community wiki.